# Forgot Monero Private Key and Spend Key

Tags: mymonero

I logged out of MyMonero.com and I never recorded "View Key (Private)" and "Spend Key (Private)", but I once noted "Account Address (Public)". How is the solution ?, I have XMR amount in MyMonero.com Wallet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an account on mymonero.com, you are given a "Private key login" which is a list of 13 words. You are also given your private spend key (the private view key can be recovered from the private spend key).

In practice, they are the same thing, represented differently. So if you have one of the two you will be able to recover your wallet.

Because Mymonero.com doesn't store your private keys or private key login, if you have lost both you will not be able to access your wallet.

Also note that your public address is something you can share with other people so they can pay you with monero and can not be used to access your funds.

Comment: Wow ... means my balance will be gone forever? Since I do not have both, I only have a Public Address.

Comment: It couldn't be better displayed when you create an account.  `Below this you will find your thirteen word "Private Login Key". Keeping this secure and private is very important, as it is the only way that you will be able to login to your MyMonero account.`